# Upgrade 2.2.3 to 2.3.10 grails

Tags: grails, version, upgrade

I'm trying to migrate the version of grails 2.2.3 to 2.3.10 however I am not succeeding. 
Made as required documentation, looked releases, however nothing. 
The project also runs put life that will make a requisition only get 404 as the answer.

Thank's.

Comment: Be sure to update the following files: application.properties, Config.groovy, BuildConfig.groovy, DataSource.groovy, web.xml, applicationContext.xml, and any *.tld files. Install grails 2.3.10 and run `grails create-app 2-3-10-base` to get the base files to the updated version of Grails, then copy and paste what you need from the 2-3-10-base project to your project you are trying to update.

Comment: to check what has changed between 2.2.3 and 2.3.10 create a default grails app with both versions and compare them. It is the easiest way to get an overview about the differences. You can see what has changed and where you have to adjust your configuration.